# Joining 2 time strings

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a problem. where I am defining date and time as string in below mentioned format.

```
date1 = '2016-12-1'
time1 = '10:30 AM'
time2 = '11:30 PM'
```

I have another string `add_time = '01:50'` type of variables is string.

what I'm looking for is:

```
new_date_and_time = time1 + add_time
```

so that it returns
`date1 and new_date_and_time`

```
> 2016-12-1, 12:20 PM (10:30 AM + 1:50)
```

but if I am adding `time2 + add_time` the date is also changed,
so it should print `2016-12-2, 1:20 AM`

Is there any package which can do this?

Comment: The question is a little confusing. I think what you're asking for is `date1` and `time1` to be combined as a `datetime` and then add a `timedelta` using the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module?

Comment: I misread the question, I understand now. Is `2016-12-2, 1:20 AM` the format you want for the result? It makes things a bit more complicated to work with in general as opposed to `isotime` or 24 hour clock e.g. `2016-12-2 01:20:00` etc.

Comment: @roganjosh anyone would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Convert strings to `datetime` object, then add time using `timedelta`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date1 = '2016-12-1'
time1 = '10:30 AM'

date_object = datetime.strptime(date1 + ' ' + time1, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')
new_date_object = date_object + timedelta(hours=1) + timedelta(minutes=50)
```

Comment: I originally thought they wanted a `timedelta` but actually this is a hard-coded solution. I would suggest `datetime.combine()` and then a way of parsing `add_time` into a `timedelta` without hard-coding.